# CodeIgniter 4 : Upload File

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem uploading a file in my form using CodeIgniter 4 and I can't find what's wrong. Can you help me, please? The name of the file is ok, the problem is that it doesn't move the file in the specified directory because I get this error: Call to a member function move() on null.
WRITEPATH has the value: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\writable\

The part of the view where I upload looks like this :

```
<div class="card-body">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Fisier</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="customFile" id="customFile" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Alege Fisierul</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the part of the controller function where I try to move the file in a specific folder looks like this :

```
$img = $this->request->getFile('customFile');
$img->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads');
```

I take the name of the file with this : `$this->request->getVar('customFile')`

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to a member function move() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268922/call-to-a-member-function-move-on-null)

Comment: Can you show your entire form please? Can you also post the output of $_FILES? Maybe you forgot yo put your form as multipart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked in Codeigniter 4:

```
 $file = $this->request->getFile('file');

        if (!$file->isValid()) {
            return $this->fail($file->getErrorString());
        }

        $file->move(ROOTPATH . 'public\uploads\documents');

        $name = $file->getName();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In **Controller** Like this...

```
$config['upload_path'] = './upload/painting/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg'; // here you want to define file type
    $config['max_width'] = '250';
    $config['max_height'] = '300';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    //  $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic');
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('ptn_url')) {
          $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    //    print_r($data);
          $_POST['ptn_url'] = "upload/painting/" . $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
          $_POST['user_id'] = $this->session->user_data['user_id'];
```

in **routes.php** file which is located at config folder
you need to define path for store image
like this...

```
$route['upload-image'] = 'user';
$route['store-image'] = 'user/add';
$route['painting/(:num)'] = 'painting';
```

for More Reference about File Upload [Visit **CodeIgniter 3 File Upload**](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html)

I hope this is helps to you...

Thank You...